# Null mock in the constructor test class with MockitoExtension from mockito-junit-jupiter

Tags: java, mockito, junit5

By using the `@MockitoExtension` extension from `mockito-junit-jupiter`, mocks are null in the test class constructor.

Used dependencies :

**mockito-junit-jupiter:2.18.0

unit-jupiter-api:5.1.1**

We could reproduce the issue with only a mock field but the use of the mock by the object under test constructor illustrates well the typical scenario :

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.mockito.junit.jupiter.MockitoExtension;

@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class FooTest {

    @Mock
    Bar mockBar;
    Foo foo;

    public FooTest() {
        foo = new Foo(mockBar); // mockBar is null here
    }

    @Test
    public void doThis() {
        Mockito.when(mockBar.doThat())
               .thenReturn(Mockito.anyInt());
        // ...
    }

}
```

As a result the mock object is walking around but not associated to the `Foo` object under test.
Why ?  What workaround use ?

Comment: That could never work. The `mockBar` field has not been initialized by the time the constructor is invoked. Thus `mockBar` will always be `null` with that setup. This has nothing to do with JUnit. Rather, this is simply how Java works.

Answer (score 6):

Solution 1 :

Replace the constructor initialization by `@InjectMocks` :

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.junit.jupiter.MockitoExtension;

@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class FooTest {

    @Mock
    Bar mockBar;

    @InjectMocks
    Foo foo;    

    @Test
    public void doThis() {
        Mockito.when(mockBar.doThat())
               .thenReturn(Mockito.anyInt());
        // ...
    }

}
```

This works but using `@InjectMocks` is also a taste question because
if all injection strategy fail, then Mockito won't report failure.
This not required injection may annoy you.   If it is the case, you can use the next one way.

Solution 2 :

Replace the constructor initialization by a method annotated with `@BeforeEach` :

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.mockito.junit.jupiter.MockitoExtension;

@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class FooTest {

    @Mock
    Bar mockBar;
    Foo foo;

    @BeforeEach
    public void beforEach() {
        foo = new Foo(mockBar); 
    }

    @Test
    public void doThis() {
        Mockito.when(mockBar.doThat())
               .thenReturn(Mockito.anyInt());
        // ...
    }

}
```

Comment: I wouldn’t consider the latter solution to be a _workaround_ at all. It’s exactly why @BeforeEach exists in Jupiter.